# Renaming with if condition in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R. One of its column (variable) is tumor site eg. (intestine, colon, lung, stomach, bladder). I need to categorize those sites according to the system. For example, I need if the site is the stomach, intestine, colon to form a new column renaming those sites with gastrointestinal.so I can decrease options in the "site of tumor" variable. part of data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEnBi.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data for reproducibility, the `base::dput`-function my help you with that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problem can be resolved in a few ways:

1. merge/join
2. `dplyr::case_when` or `data.table::fcase`
3. named-vector "dictionary" of sorts

### Sample data

(Ideally you would have provided this, I'll make up something.)

```r
dat <- data.frame(tumorsite = rep(c("intestine", "colon", "lung", "stomach", "bladder"),2))
```

### Merge/join

(This topic is well-informed by [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272.)

```r
newdat <- data.frame(tumorsite = c("intestine", "colon", "lung", "stomach", "bladder"), newcolumn = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "C"))
newdat
#   tumorsite newcolumn
# 1 intestine         A
# 2     colon         A
# 3      lung         B
# 4   stomach         A
# 5   bladder         C

### base R
merge(dat, newdat, by = "tumorsite", all.x = TRUE)
#    tumorsite newcolumn
# 1    bladder         C
# 2    bladder         C
# 3      colon         A
# 4      colon         A
# 5  intestine         A
# 6  intestine         A
# 7       lung         B
# 8       lung         B
# 9    stomach         A
# 10   stomach         A

### dplyr
dplyr::left_join(dat, newdat, by = "tumorsite")
```

### case_when (fcase)

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(newcolumn = case_when(
    tumorsite %in% c("intestine", "colon", "stomach") ~ "A", 
    tumorsite %in% c("lung", "pharynx") ~ "B", 
    tumorsite %in% c("bladder", "ureter") ~ "C", 
    TRUE ~ "unk")
  )
#    tumorsite newcolumn
# 1  intestine         A
# 2      colon         A
# 3       lung         B
# 4    stomach         A
# 5    bladder         C
# 6  intestine         A
# 7      colon         A
# 8       lung         B
# 9    stomach         A
# 10   bladder         C
```

### dictionary vector

```r
## using previously-defined newdat, but can be made directly/manually
newdat_vec <- setNames(newdat$newcolumn, newdat$tumorsite)
newdat_vec
# intestine     colon      lung   stomach   bladder 
#       "A"       "A"       "B"       "A"       "C" 

dat$newcolumn <- newdat_vec[dat$tumorsite]
dat
#    tumorsite newcolumn
# 1  intestine         A
# 2      colon         A
# 3       lung         B
# 4    stomach         A
# 5    bladder         C
# 6  intestine         A
# 7      colon         A
# 8       lung         B
# 9    stomach         A
# 10   bladder         C
```

Comment: Could you explain more. I will create a reference for naming my data?

Comment: oh thank you very much appreciated. You are smart. I created a reference and imported it into my script. Then applied this list using your code and it renames 25000 items according to my reference.  Thank you